# Equality of term and codeline

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, logical-operators

Can anyone explain me please step-by-step, how this equality can hold?

```
((a^b)&~b)|(~(a^b)&b)  == a
```

What is the best way to do it?

Comment: do you mean `((a^b)&~b)|(~(a^b)&b) == a` ? (==, not =)

Comment: In C that's not equality but assignment (`==` is equality), and it's going to fail because the left side of the assignment is not a modifiable lvalue.

Comment: What's the purpose of `logical-operators` tag? There are no logical operators involved here.

Comment: every bit handled separatelly. so we can assume that both *a* and *b* 1 bit long and look for 2 case only `b == 0` and `((a^0)&~0)|(~(a^0)&0) == (a) | (0) == a;` and `b == 1` - `((a^1)&~1)|(~(a^1)&1) == (0) | (a) == a;`

Comment: Because of this `| ` it makes the check to be not the right check the Author maybe expected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`(X&~Y)|(~X&Y) == X^Y //by definition of XOR`

Substituting X=a^b and Y=b:

`((a^b)&~b)|(~(a^b)&b) == (a^b)^b`

Then, the rest is simple:

`(a^b)^b == a^(b^b) == a^0 == a`

Answer (score 2):

Simply developing the xor and simplifying:

```
((a^b) & ~b) | (~(a^b) & b) ==
((a|b) & (~a|~b) & ~b) | ((a|~b) & (~a|b) & b) ==
((a|b) & ~b) | ((a|~b) & b) ==
a | a ==
a
```

Another way to see it is to define `f(a, b) = (a^b) & ~b`.
The statement becomes `f(a, b) | f(a, ~b)`, so you just have to simplify `f(a, b)`:

```
f(a, b) ==
(a^b) & ~b ==
(a|b) & (~a|~b) & ~b ==
(a|b) & ~b ==
a
```

So `f(a, b) = a` whatever `b` is, and `f(a, b) | f(a, ~b)` is simply `a | a == a`.

Answer (score 1):

a program to check :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int a, b;

  for (a = 0; a != 2; ++a) {
    for (b = 0; b != 2; ++b) {
      printf("((%d^%d)&~%d)|(~(%d^%d)&%d) = %d (a=%d, b=%d)\n",
             a,b,b,a,b,b, ((a^b)&~b)|(~(a^b)&b), a,b);
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

the execution produces :

```
((0^0)&~0)|(~(0^0)&0) = 0 (a=0, b=0)
((0^1)&~1)|(~(0^1)&1) = 0 (a=0, b=1)
((1^0)&~0)|(~(1^0)&0) = 1 (a=1, b=0)
((1^1)&~1)|(~(1^1)&1) = 1 (a=1, b=1)
```

---

For the mathematical explanation look at the remark of RbMm

Comment: For the sake of good programming practice and defensive programming: the for-conditions should be `a<2` and `b<2`, even for this simple program.

Comment: In the same way `x == 0` must be `0 == x` in case  we write '=' rather than '=='. To be frank I hate these way to write, that supposes we don't know what we do, but may be I am too pretentious ? :-)

Comment: If `a` ends up greater than 2 then something has gone majorly wrong anyway, so I don't think it matters!

Comment: As long as the whole expression is not surrounded by parentheses  we do not know for sure if that was for sure the intention of the Author from the OP code. The corect one should be `(   ( ( a ^ b ) & ~b ) | ( ~( a ^ b ) & b )   )  == a`